# web service method not working

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

i am getting blank output for the the following method i have

```
function getLocation($arr)
{
    $data = array();


        $qry = $this->db->query('select id,lat,lng from test where lat between'.$arr->lat-0.2 .'and'.$arr->lat+0.2);
        $res = $qry->row_array();
        if($qry->num_rows()==0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            foreach ($res->result() as $row)
            {
                $data['distance']=distanceBetween($arr->lat,$arr->lng,$row['lat'],$row['lng']);
                $data['id']=$row['id'];
            }
            return true;

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct code...and its working now

```
function getLocation($arr)
{
    $data = array();
    $where='';


        $this->db->select('id,lat,lng,address');
        $where = 'lat between "'.($arr->lat-0.2).'" AND "'.($arr->lat+0.2).'"';
        $this->db->where($where);
        $qry = $this->db->get('pa_test');
        $res = $qry->result();

        $i=0;
        if(count($res)>0)
        {
            foreach($res as $row)
            {
                $test=$this->distanceBetween($arr->lat,$arr->lng,$row->lat,$row->lng);
                $data[$i]['id']=$row->id;  
                $data[$i]['distance'] = $test;  
                $i++;           
            }
        }

    return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the result rather than `true` when there is result is coming from query. Your function returns `true` when query returns any result.

```
return true;
```

should be

```
return $data;
```

**Edit**

Use this query with `()` around variables

```
$qry = $this->db->query('select id,lat,lng from test 
where lat between'.($arr->lat)-(0.2) .'and'.($arr->lat)+(0.2));
```

also

```
foreach ($res->result() as $row)
```

should be

```
foreach ($qry->result_array() as $row)
```

Comment: i have changed it like this... stil not working
        if($qry->num_rows()==0)
{
    $data['value'] ='1'; 
    return $data;
   }

Comment: @Monansh May be your query returns nothing. Also see edited answer.

Comment: @Monansh To fetch the result change `$res->result()` to `$qry->result_array()`.

Comment: that query is working fine when trying on the db console... n i tried with $qry->result_array()... no change still

Answer (score 1):

First off you need:

```
$res = $qry->result_array(); // not row_array()
```

Second, you need:

```
foreach ($res as $row){
```

Then, assuming `distanceBetween`is another method inside your controller, you need:

```
$data['distance'] = $this->distanceBetween($arr->lat,$arr->lng,$row['lat'],$row['lng']);
```

Lastly, your method needs to return `$data` in the `else`clause.

Comment: Is the `$arr` argument an actual array? What does it consist of - might it be empty? Also, where does `distanceBetween`come from, and is that code reliable/tested? Is it a helper function or another method inside the same controller?

Comment: distanceBetween is a func in the same controller...i am testing it so i am only sending value forr $arr...which is not null..its not a helper func

Comment: Okay, so you definitely need `$this->distanceBetween`then. Instead of `return $data`, what happens if you `print_r($data)`?

Comment: this is a func being called in a webservice method...where is it goin to print the data if i write print_r($data) ?

Comment: How and where are you calling `getLocation($arr)`then? I assume you're assigning its returned `$data` to a variable? How do you display the output?